# Cannot get class with getElementsByClassName() on PhantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I try to find a class element associated to a button in order to validate it's presence. But it seems that I cannot get it to work. I'm using the right method for it?

I want to use PhantomJS to see if the "Add to Cart" button is there so that I can have an indication of stock availability. 
For this I made the following code:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla';
page.open('https://www.gearbest.com/3d-printers-3d-printer-kits/pp_009187500972.html', function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to access network');
    } else {
        var add = page.evaluate(function () {
            return document.getElementsByClassName("js-btnGoodsAddCart")[0];
        });     
        if (add.outerHTML.length > 0) { 
                console.log(page.title + " AVAILABLE");
            } else {
                console.log(page.title + " UNAVAILABLE");
            }
    }
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Above there is also de address I was working on. When I run the script, it just stops responding.
The HTML code I am searching in is:

```
    <div class="goodsIntro_btnWrap js-buyBtnWrap">
        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn big line2 uibtn-cart js-btnGoodsAddCart js-trackBtnAddCart ">Add to Cart</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn big uibtn-buynow js-btnGoodsBuyNow js-trackBtnBuyNow ">Buy Now</a>
        <a href="javascript:;" class="btn big btnPaypal js-btnGoodsBuyWithPaypal js-trackBtnPaypal" data-disable="false">
        <span class="lightningPayPalImg"></span></a>
    </div>
```

P.S. I can get it to work, but with document.getElementsByClassName("goodsIntro_btnWrap js-buyBtnWrap"). The innerHTML (where "js-btnGoodsAddCart" code is) is not displayed.

Comment: try adding the user agent 
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36';

Comment: Oddly it works only with page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla'. With page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.106 Safari/537.36' I get an "Unable to access network" error.